# Apache Rewrite List of URLS

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I need to be able to rewrite a list of currently URLs to new URLs on a different domain.

For example

```
http://oldhost/information/site-map -> http://newhost/regions/
http://oldhost/links/ -> http://newhost/links-to-whatever
```

But in the case that the URL does not match any of the oldhost URLs in the list, redirect to `http://newhost`

Answer (score 1):

Put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?oldhost\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^site-map/?$ http://newhost/regions/? [L,NC,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?oldhost\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^links/?$ http://newhost/links-to-whatever? [L,NC,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?oldhost\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://newhost%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I am using it for a .com.au domain though. So I have: RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?oldhost\.com\.au$ [NC] instead.

Comment: Which URL didn't redirect for you?